# Laptop beeping on mute when trying to access or delete something that doesn't exist

Tags: audio

My laptop (Lenovo Legion 15 5ACH6A) with Archcraft installed is beeping while muted in the following situations:

- When I use arrow keys to try to move at the end of a directory in my file manager:
  (left arrow in this case)
  [image: Thunar File Manager]

- When I try to delete a character in an empty string (Delete or Backspace)
- When I shutdown or reboot

I don't get why. I obviously have it on mute so why does it still beep?

Thanks in advance